# Time based auto-reloading of Jinja element in Python/Flask without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, ajax

So I've been trying to get this to work with Ajax and JQuery, but I can't seem to get it. I'm new to both of these. Sorry if this is trivial, I've been searching and working off previous answers for awhile now.

Info:

I have a Jinja tag in my page html that I would like to update once per second:

```
 <pre id="#system_info_tag">{{ system_info_text }}</pre>
```

The information is originally (and successfully) populated from my main python script in a larger function called get_system_info():

```
@app.route('/')
def root():
    return render_template('system_info.html', system_info_text=get_system_info())
```

I would like the element to automatically reload once per second though, so I am trying to do that with JS as follows (which I thought would re-run my python function, as re-loading the page updates it):

```js
function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#system_info_tag").load(location.href + " #system_info_tag");
    }, 1000);
});
```

which is loaded in my html file with:

```
<script src="static/js/update_refresh.js"></script>
```

The page loads fine with the correct information, but the element doesn't auto-reload. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: as a hint throw a `console.log("updating system info")` in your update function ... also i dont think you want to load `location.href + " #system_info_tag"` that doesnt make any sense

Comment: Quick glance, you don't want the '#' in the id attribute on the <pre>.  That's going to mess up your selector.  You will also want to do what Soviut suggested so the code actually runs.  Also, I would suggest possibly changing to from a setInterval to a setTimeout that performs another setTimeout after it is done.  1000 is a pretty short time to poll and the changes for the requests to start stacking on themselves is probably pretty high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**main.py**

```
@app.route('/')
def root():
    return render_template('system_info.html', system_info_text=get_system_info())

@app.route("/sys_info.json")
def system_info(): # you need an endpoint on the server that returns your info...
    return get_system_info()
```

**templates/system_info.html**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<div id="content">{{ system_info }}</div> {# this is the original system_info passed in from the root view #}

<script>
setInterval(function(){ // load the data from your endpoint into the div
    $("#content").load("/sys_info.json")
},1000)
</script>
```

I think anyway

Answer (score 0):

The self-invoking function you've wrapped your script in isn't being called. It should be:

```
(function() {
  // your code
})();
```

Note the extra `()` at the end. That's what's actually calling that function that's defined inside the previous parenthesis.

Next, in your HTML, remove the `#` from your `id` on the `<pre>` tag. The `#` is only used in selectors, not actual attributes.

```
<pre id="system_info_tag">{{ system_info_text }}</pre>
```

Next, remove the space from the beginning of your anchor you're appending to the URL.

```
location.href + '#system_info_tag'
```

Finally, check your Network tab in your browser's dev tools to see if those `load()` requests are even firing. If they are, see which URL they're calling. There is a good chance they're hitting the wrong URL and won't load anything as a result.

Comment: even if it were it would not work ... there are more problems than this

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was unbalanced with those. I also added the closing call, but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: OP doesnt have an endpoint that updates the info he wants... I can pretty much guarantee he doesnt want to embed the current page inside a div on the current page however